# Is there a way to show each CPU's load separately?

Tags: activity-monitor, cpu

I'm seeking an equivalent of a common Linux based process monitor, which shows a history graph for each CPU core.  This can help identify programs that are effectively using all the cores (here, Google Chrome).  Is there a way to get Apple system monitor to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of anything with that kind of detail, but Apple's own Activity Monitor [Applications/Utilities] can show a basic history graph per core.  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>3</kbd>  to initiate.

[image]

System shows in red, user in green, btw.

Comment: +1, protip: to make window screenshot press: ⌘⇧4 and then press spacebar. It'll look as in @Graham Miln image.

Comment: yup, one of those things I'm aware of, but my trigger-happy snapshot finger doesn't have the patience sometimes ;)

Comment: there, fixed it ;)

Answer (score 4):

Another application which may be helpful (depending on your needs) is `Instruments.app` included in Xcode.

It doesn't allow a continuous easy monitoring like `iStat Menus` or `Activity Monitor` do, due to the fact that some user interaction is needed to set up a sample and start recording it. On the other hand you may monitor single applications – a feature the aforementioned apps don't accomplish.
From a programmer's perspective this may be very useful.

[image: instruments]

Usage: Instruments Help <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> -> Viewing Collected Data -> Monitoring Multiple Core Usage

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Activity Monitor**'s CPU History.

> Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.app

Within Activity Monitor, select the menu item **Window** > **CPU History** to reveal a per CPU load history.  The output is not as detailed as the Linux process monitor in your question but it is free.

[image: Activity Monitor CPU History]

Apple's [OS X: Activity Monitor shows one CPU Usage graph on systems with more than four cores](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202060) explains more about the behaviour of the CPU graph.

Third party products, such as [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), are available that extend your options.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [iStatMenus](http://bjango.com), a commercial app, available which allows such stat to be monitored.

[image: Menubar view by core]
[image: Extended menubar view]
[image: Setup options window]