# My Mac recently using RAM like hell?

Tags: macos, memory, gmail, performance

I have 8 GB of ram and I have only 1.25GB free memory left, not enough to run 2 tabs of gmail. for chrome keep asking me to kill the process of my Gmail which 2-3 days ago I'm always have like 2-3GB free memory after opening 2 gmail accounts and some others websites.

I also installed auto memory clean to help me get more memory back but recently when my mac start, a few minutes later memory almost dropped to 0GB so my memory cleaner app keep to clean memory after that memory consuming so fast and repeat above process again. Memory clean doesn't solve my problem in a long term.

I have closed all the apps to free memory and I see that when idle I should have more memory back but it's not.

So I looked into Activity Monitor and Memory clean app, I saw 2 things that consuming lots of memory which I don't think it's true.

I'm trying to use cleanmymac 2 to help me solve the issue specially to kick away some file cache problem, but I don't see any difference.

Comment: Please take a picture of Activity Monitor and show us what you think is not true. To further investigate a/several culprit(s) check my answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159356/is-there-a-way-to-show-each-cpus-load-separately) and  start Instruments.app and take a second screenshot.

Comment: We know you can not post pics in here, but you can use a link to them. You are speaking in riddles. What 2 things are consuming memory?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97341/why-is-my-mac-using-so-much-memory/125707#125707

Answer (score 6):

First of all it's probably a good idea to stop using that memory cleaner app. They aren't necessary these days; if they ever were. The memory systems on modern operating systems are perfectly capable of maintaining themselves. The way these memory cleaner application work is by claiming a huge chunk of RAM, thereby forcing everything not critical out of RAM, and then releasing the RAM they've requested. Your swapping something that has been fine tuned over years by a lot of very smart people, with some guy wielding a mallet.

This could actually be the reason you are seeing your free RAM drop to zero. It could be the memory cleaner app itself.

The idea that you need to have a large amount of RAM sitting "free" is just wrong. When you close applications the RAM isn't necessarily immediately freed. All modern operating systems keep recently used files cached in RAM so that if you (or the system) decide to reopen something recently closed the files open quicker.

If you do have a performance problem with Gmail in Chrome the problem is likely elsewhere. I highly doubt it has anything to do with the amount of free RAM on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

First, Chrome uses a lot of memory, especially if you have had it open several days.

Usually closing apps helps recover and frees portions of memory, but still keeps some for the very same reason RAM is used.

After closing you're apps, you can `purge` command in your terminal to force disk cache to be purged (flushed and emptied).

```
sudo purge
```

Enter your administrative password, wait a few seconds. Your Mac should be close to initial boot conditions.

`man purge` for more information:

> purge -- force disk cache to be purged (flushed and emptied)
>
> Purge can be used to approximate initial boot conditions with a cold disk buffer cache for performance analysis. It does not affect anonymous memory that has been allocated through malloc, vm_allocate, etc.